# How do I batch place a series of images onto a background image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I think context will help with this one.

I am trying to put some stickers onto an image of a model--think tattoos.

Picture this: I have an image of someone's back. Now I have 10 sticker images.

The end result that I'd like is 10 images--each one with the image of the back with one of the stickers on it.

Each sticker image is the same dimension so that's not a problem.

I feel like there must be a way to do this--batch apply images onto another images but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: photoshop is not necessary but BATCH processing is. can illustrator do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can Batch it in Photoshop.
Think the opening file is your tatoo.
Create a new script:
Increase the artwork size as per the model image. Import it, move the layer under the tatoo. Select the tatoo layer, move, rotate, distort, apply blending, whatever you like (since they all have the same size)... Run your batch and that's it basically...

[image: script]

[image: batch]

Comment: Vinny this is exactly the answer and help I was looking for. I can't thank you enough. It never occurred to me for whatever reason to add the model image underneath :) Incredibly helpful merci beaucoup!

Comment: @OtisFunkmeyer De rien^^ Glad I could help. You can mark answer as correct for the users who could have the same question in the future. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator and Photoshop have Action Automation for repetitive tasks. Actions   are operation walkthrough lists. You can record the manipulation for one file as you do it. Then you can launch your action to process every file of a folder.

The recorded action walks through your sticker folder, adds a constant back behind the sticker, maybe resizes and moves the sticker and saves the combined files into your output folder.

Learn from Adobe's tutorials how to use the Action Automation.

The action does exactly same movements for every file. Any cleverness or automatic case by case processing differently needs programming language scripting. It needs a competent programmer. It is beyond the scope of this answer.